# How to use laravel collection methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-collection

I'm trying to query a nested relation and getting the count of distant model count, I'm transforming this to a variable but it is not happening:

```
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Research');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($company) {
        $company->contacts_association_count = $company->interactionSummaries
            ->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')
            ->collapse()
            ->sum();
    });
```

When I try to `dd($companies)` or even `return $companies` I get null values placed in each array index

[image: Null values in array keys]

But when I do `dd($company)` inside transform

```
->transform(function ($company) {
    $company->contacts_association_count = $company->interactionSummaries
        ->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')
        ->collapse()
        ->sum();
    dd($company);
});
```

I get the single collection which states my query is running properly:

[image: single instance]

If I remove transform part and simply get the collection:

```
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Research');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get()
```

I'm getting the desired output, But I don't know what it is happening after transform execution. In fact it is not plucking and adding the sum, as I'm getting all 0 in the counts.

[image: collection count]

I've marked them with red. Help me out in this

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a `return` statement in the transform closure.

Comment: I've updated the question, the collection is not doing the sum as desired.

Comment: So what do you have? Have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put *return $company* statement in transform.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Where should this be put in the code. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.